# Joomla menu not showing

Tags: php, joomla

I know nothing about Joomla, but I just need to get this done. Suddenly my Joomla site menu is not showing up. I cant see anything under the Menu Manager->Main Menu->Menu Items. But there are rows in the jos_menu table. Why isnt it showing up?

Comment: show us a screen-shot of your `#_menu` table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the php was upgraded to 5.3 and all sorts of problems are cropping up. I resolved it by changing the following:

in yourjoomladirectory/libraries/joomla/html/html.php

```
return call_user_func_array( array( $className, $func ), $args );
```

to

```
return call_user_func_array( array( $className, $func ), &$args );
```

and in yourjoomladirectory/modules/mod_mainmenu/helper.php

```
function buildXML(&$params)
```

to

```
function buildXML($params)
```

Hope this helps someone.