# Joomla 1.5.3 will not display Menu Items in Menu Item Manager

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I'm currently running with PHP 5.3.4. I found that this should be compatible here https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/786/what-is-the-maximum-version-of-php-that-joomla-1-5-will-run

However I did have some PHP issues that I resolved with this link: [Joomla menu not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293644/joomla-menu-not-showing)

After doing this I was able to see the menu items show up correctly for my site.  However in the Menu Item Manager inside the Joomla admin the errors listed below are thrown when debugged. Menu items will not display at all and the list is blank. What is causing these errors to be thrown and not display my menu items in the Joomla Admin yet display on the website perfectly?

Warning: Parameter 4 to JHTMLMenu::treerecurse() expected to be a reference, value given in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\libraries\joomla\html\html.php on line 87

Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\administrator\components\com_menus\models\list.php on line 143

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\administrator\components\com_menus\models\list.php on line 147 Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\administrator\components\com_menus\views\list\view.php on line 198

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\administrator\components\com_menus\views\list\view.php on line 66

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Revised title and question asked. Hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Ciro, by replacing the following files in my case resolved my issue. There was not a need to replace all Joomla files.

```
helper.php - found here modules\mod_mainmenu 
html.php - found here libraries\joomla\html 
view.php - found here administrator\components\com_menus\views\list
```

Comment: My website also menu item not listing can you help me with any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what Joomla 1.5 version do you have?

Remember that only the 1.15.16+ are PHP 5.3 compatible

Look this Post [Joomla 1.5 and PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294502/joomla-1-5-and-php-5-3) with the same error on line:

`libraries\joomla\html\html.php on line 87`

I think that you can try to replace the files with error with PhilETaylor version https://github.com/PhilETaylor/Joomla1.5.999

good Luck!

Comment: Running with Joomla version 1.5.3 this should be compatible with PHP 5.3.4 from what I read.

Comment: Joomla 1.5.3 ? i think that the last stable version is Joomla! 1.5.26...
Try to replace the files with PhilETaylor, first replace `libraries\joomla\html\html.php` to see if the warning is hidden

Comment: Ok so I replaced the following files:

helper.php - found here modules\mod_mainmenu

html.php - found here libraries\joomla\html

view.php - found here administrator\components\com_menus\views\list

That resolved my issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: i'm glad to know it´s all ok!